# Github actions cannot read my config.json thats in .gitignore but my repo is public and cannot push config.json

Tags: node.js, github

My yml file inside .github/workflows [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dr7JN.png)

```
name: Node Integrate

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Use Node.js 16.x
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 16.x
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: rm -rf node_modules && yarn install --frozen-lockfile
      - name: Run the app
        run: yarn start
```

Im not sure how to get github actions to read config.json when its on .gitignore but i cannot push it since i dont want my keys leaked to public

Comment: Why would your workflow use a file that's not in your repository? Anyway I think you can let git track the file by `git add config.json`, and do a commit, but I don't know if changes to the file will be tracked

Comment: But obviously if the file is ignored, then you don't want it in git...

Comment: This is what [secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/managing-codespaces-for-your-organization/managing-encrypted-secrets-for-your-repository-and-organization-for-github-codespaces) are for